# ASP.Net MVC with complex routes - how to keep it "sane"?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a client who wishes to use a URL naming convention along the lines of:

```
/{subjectarea}/{subject}/{action}
```

Which is fine - this works brilliantly, with one controller per subject area, and having the action after the id (subject) is no issue at all.

However, it then gets complicated, as the client then wants to further continue the hierarchy:

```
/{subjectarea}/{subject}/{action}/{tightlyrelatedsubject}/{tightlyrelatedsubjectvariables}/{tightlyrelatedsubjectaction}
```

I have a controller for the tightly related subject (its just another subject area) which handles all of the admin side, but the client insists on having the public view hung off of the parent subject rather than its own root.

How can I do this while avoiding breaking the entire principals of MVC, and also avoiding re-implementing a ton of ASP.Net MVC provided functionality in my subject area controller just to be able to handle the related subjects from that same controller?

Is it possible to somehow call the related subjects controller from within the parent subject controller, and return the resulting view (as this would keep the separation of functionality for the subjects to their own controllers)?  If that is possible, it would solve a heck of a lot of issues with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution which solves my given issue - hope it solves someone elses.

As mentioned in my comment to Robert Harvey, all I actually need is another route which doesn't use the first two or three components as the controller, action and id, but instead takes those values from later on - if you hang this off of a static value in the route as well, its much easier to do.

So, here is the url I decided on to simplify the route:

```
/{subjectarea}/{subject}/related/{tightlyrelatedsubject}/{tightlyrelatedsubjectvariables}/{tightlyrelatedsubjectaction}
```

The route which satisfies this URL is as follows:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "RelatedSubjects",
            "{parentcontroller}/{parentsubject}/related/{controller}/{id}/{action}",
            new { controller = "shoes", action = "view", id = "all" }
        );
```

On the subsequent controller action, I can ask for parameter values for parentcontroller and parentsubject so I can filter out the related item to just be specific to the given parent subject - problem solved!

This route needs to be above the ones which just deal with the first two values, otherwise you run the risk of another route map hijacking the request.

I could do this entirely without the /related/ static portion as the route could easily match on number of values alone, and infact I may indeed do so - however, I consider it better for later administration if there is a static item in there to confirm the use of the route.

I hope this helps someone!

Comment: This is exactly what I was after also, using a new view controller but maintaining access to the parent controller and parent parameters. Thanks for posting your findings.

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do it is specify a wildcard route (notice the asterisk):

```
routes.MapRoute("subjects", "{action}/{*path}",
    new { controller = "Subjects", action = "Index" });
```

This allows the controller to receive the entire path string after the `action`.

You can then obtain the hierarchy of subjects in the controller method like so:

```
string[] subjects = path.Split('/');
```

Once you have that, you can do anything you want, including dispatching different subjects to different handling methods for processing.

Comment: Thats the way I considered prior to posting the question - however, it has the side effect of throwing out most of what ASP.Net MVC provides me in that there is a lot of "routing" I would then have to do by hand within the controller method handling the action - that was what I was attempting to avoid.  If I could pick out the relatedsubjects controller value, action and id, then I can leave everything up to the target controller, rather than having to reimplement everything on the current controller (which would also violate the single responsibility principle).  Does that make sense?

Comment: Its worth pointing out that the problem is not how to get the values from the route, its how to get the resulting view from the correct controller, while within a different controller - if it were possible to do that .... and I trail off in thought as something occurs to me.  All I really need is another stati where the first three values are *not* considered the controller, action or id, but just more data and the actaul values for controller, action and id are taken from further down the route.... hmmm