# ASP MVC 3 Custom Route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

How do I handle url like this:

```
{subdomain}.{domainname}/{areas}/{controller}/{action}
```

For example: `user1.contoso.com/Manage/User/View`

I want it to be route:

```
{area} = Manage
{controller} = User
{action} = View
{username} = user1 // View action parameter
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1):

Generally routes are defined in the file **Global.asax** in the method RegisterRoutes

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");


        routes.MapRoute(
            "Export",                                                            // Route name
            "Export/{action}/{table}",                                       // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Export", action = "AsExcel", table = "" }  // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
        );
    }
```

With a definition like above you can use a separate route for **ExportController** such that the default action is **AsExcel**

in the case of route as the one you have described, I am not sure if ***Areas*** is part of the MVC pattern.

Still for what it is worth, you may have some benefit from this thread
[ASP.Net MVC with complex routes - how to keep it "sane"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9556831/asp-net-mvc-with-complex-routes-how-to-keep-it-sane)

Comment: I'm not sure how you could get at the {subdomain} by doing what you describe.  Can you give a specific example where the url `surya.google.com/export/file/worksheet` is handled so that `surya` comes through as a parameter?

Comment: @dtryon AFAIK sub-domain should be handled with a URL rewrite at server instead of application because it is really task of the server to redirect the client to correct sub-domain. Something like what is discussed here  http://forums.iis.net/t/1155754.aspx/1?Sub+Domain+Rewrite might help to use regular routes in a way that is required